# Search bar from API Vue js

Tags: vue.js

I have a table which get the data from Api and i am trying to have a search bar for this table when  search for any name it should retrn just what i write

here is my app component :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="flex justify-center">
      <input type="text" v-model="search" />
    </div>
    <div class="user flex justify-center text-3xl">
      <BaseTable :data="filteredData" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import BaseTable from "./components/BaseTable";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      data: {
        headers: ["id", "city", "name", "address"],
        rows: [],
      },
      search: null,
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.fetchUsers();
  },
  components: {
    BaseTable,
  },
  methods: {
    fetchUsers() {
      this.$axios
        .get("https://605c40b36d85de00170d9a8f.mockapi.io/user/zurich")
        .then(({ data }) => {
          this.mapper(data);
          console.log(data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
    mapper(data) {
      this.data.rows = data.map((i) => {
        return [i.id, i.city, i.name, i.address];
      });
      console.log(this.data);
    },
  },
  computed: {
    filteredData() {
      if (this.search) {
        return this.data.rows.filter((item) =>
          item.toLowerCase().includes(this.search)
        );
      } else {
        return this.data;
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style src="../assets/tailwind.css"/>
```

and here is my table component :

```
<template>
  <table class="mt-12 border-2 border-gray-600">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th
          v-for="header in data.headers"
          :key="header"
          class="text-left border-l-2 border-gray-600 border-b-2 border-gray-600 bg-red-400"
        >
          {{ header }}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(rows, index) in data.rows" :key="index">
        <td v-for="row in rows" :key="row" class="border-l-2 border-gray-600">
          {{ row }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    data: Object,
    default: {},
  },
};
</script>
<style src="../assets/tailwind.css"/>
```

that what i tried but it doesnt work it dosent give any error or results ?

any help i am new on Vue js
you can take a look on the code in this sandbox :
https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-brown-qs9pl?file=/src/App.vue:0-1281

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are mainly two problems:

1. `item` in your filter is an array of strings, so you need to iterate over each string:

   ```
   rows: this.data.rows.filter(item =>
       item.some(i => i.toLowerCase().includes(this.search))
   )
   ```
2. Your Table component expects and object containing headers and rows, but your filter is only returning rows. This can be fixed using spread operator to return other properties in data:

   ```
   return {
     ...this.data,
     rows: this.data.rows.filter((item) =>
       item.some((i) => i.toLowerCase().includes(this.search))
     ),
   };
   ```

[image: Edit unruffled-hypatia-zw7yd]

- [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)
- [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

I'd suggest doing the data fetching and filter in the table component itself and passing just the search string as a prop to it, this way you can only filter the rows in it.

---

Leaving my first, simpler approach that only searches by name:

I removed your mapper method and modified your method like this:

```
filteredData() {
  if (this.search) {
    return({
      ...this.data,
      rows: this.data.rows.filter((item) => {
        return item.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search);
      }),
    });
  } else {
    return this.data;
  }
},
```

and updated the inner loop to work with an object like:

```
<tr v-for="(row, index) in data.rows" :key="index">
    <td v-for="(value, name) in row" :key="name" class="border-l-2 border-gray-600">
      {{ value }}
    </td>
</tr>
```

[image: Edit angry-worker-2izk6]

Answer (score 0):

1. For a short answer the data that you give to the component is different from the data after filtering.

```js
data: {
        headers: ["id", "city", "name", "address"],
        rows: [],
},
```

versus

```js
    filteredData() {
      /// which only return the `rows` data only
    },
```

2. Please use a more specific name rather than `data` for data. This will save you in the future.
3. Other than that @TJ had already given you a very good answer.